# Set folder view - per folder preferences

Tags: 15.04, nautilus, directory

is there a way with Ubuntu 15.04 or less recent versions to set view preferences on a per-folder basis? Something like this folder should be a list, this one should be icons and so on.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use Nemo

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
```

Comment: Is this as tricky as the change from unity to gnome? I tried it once and I awarded myself a clean reinstall because everything went awful...

Comment: no, using different file manager

Comment: Why use that 3rd party PPA when you can just install from the repos ??? -1

Comment: I'm not sure if we can install from the repos. but this working fine on my Ubuntu

Comment: The one in the repos almost broke my system, the one from webupd8 does not even start... I'm quite puzzled to say the least